# Change Directory in Same Directory Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$dir2 = Split-Path $scriptpath
Write-Host "My Directory is $dir"

# install Java
Get-ChildItem $dir -Include "*.msi", "*.exe" | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Format-Table Name
Write-Host "Installing Java.."
Start-Process -FilePath $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "jre1.8.0_161.msi") -ArgumentList '-qn' -Wait
sleep 5

# disable java autoupdate
Write-Host "Disabling Java Update.."
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v SunJavaUpdateSched /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" /v EnableJavaUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
sleep 5

# copying files
cd $dir2
Copy-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot\* -Destination "C:\Users\ekarazhov\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment" -Force
```

Here is my code. Everything is working but copying the file. File that i am copying is "deployment.properties" its a configuration file for java. Problem that i am encountering is that when i am doing `Copy-item -Path $PSScriptRoot\deployment.properties` powershell thinks that last part is some kind of directory. So i am thinking of creating a new folder with in the current folder called Deployment. CD to that directory and do Copy-Item -Path new folder with an * Which should copy all the files from that new folder. However i can't find a proper powershell command to change directory in the same folder. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: So i got everything to work but the last portion.

Copy-Item -Path $RootDir\Deployment\*.* -Destination "$env:Userprofile\Appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment" -Force -Recurse
I packaged it with SCCM. If i go to C:\Windows\ccmcache\5 and run just the line from the powershell Copy-Item -Path $RootDir\Deployment\*.* -Destination "$env:Userprofile\Appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment" -Force -Recurse i get an error Cannot find path 'C:\Deployment' because it does not exist.